# Problem with interacting with child process

Tags: python, c#, console-application, stdout, wrapper

I'm building a GUI wrapper for terraria or tModLoader dedicated server.
Firstly, I was building discord bot for manage my terraria server with python. Then I'm struck with a problem that makes me to waste almost 1 week. The program I made seemed to work fine. Until the time when "Choose World :" message should appear. When the time has come the program freezes.
I thought root cause of the problem is the dedicated server uses Console.Write to print "Choose World :" Message. So my program can't read line because there is no LF. Some thoughtless trying like use pywinpty or asyncio were did nothing to me. After that I changed my goal to make GUI wrapper for the server. Still I have the problem. Maybe It is about buffer thing? and I can send input neither. is it because terraria server doesn't receive input through stdin? The later was what I were thinking. So I have been trying with that Until now. Yet I got nothing.
I am sorry for my lack of english skill that possibly made my question vague and for my programming skill. If you need more information to answer my question. I will give you information as much as i can. I hope you can answer me with Python or C#

[The Code](https://github.com/mikrono/TerrariaServerWrapper)

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If2Xp.png)

[Result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7YAM.png)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal
I think this might help......