# How can I read and write into child process with conpty?

Tags: python, c#, wrapper, pty

I want to build a GUI wrapper for terraria dedicated server.
Firstly, I decided that I will make console viewer. But I were struck with problems. Problems are like these, I can't get a line of text that should appear before server starts recieving input. And I can't give input to the server. I thought the problem is about how it accepts and prints. So I chose to use conpty. Then the program could print "Choose World:' message. But it still can't properly print output and didn't reacted for my input. How can i do those things properly?
C# or Python both are okay.

[My previous question(Related)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68881634/problem-with-interacting-with-child-process)

[Code of program](https://github.com/mikrono/TerrariaServerWrapper/tree/conpty)

[Result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If2Xp.png)

[image: result of conpty version of my program]

Comment: I could did this with winpty.NET.  But I couldn't build the program with any CPU settting. Seems like winpty.NET has only x64 version of dll. I will try to find another way later or not.

Comment: If you are interested in the way how I did it. See winpty.net branch.